# How to find out if number X is in range of number Y? (But in a circular way)

Tags: math

Imagine I have a range of numbers 0-9.
And I want to find out if number X is in range of number Y, and the range would be 2.

So for example with Y=5, X is in range if X is 3,4,5,6 or 7.

```
   --Y-- 
0123456789
```

For this I could do:

```
isInRange = abs(X - Y) <= 2
```

But I need it in a way, that the range is kind of circular, starting with 0 again:

```
     --Y--    -     --Y-    --     --Y    Y--     --    -Y--     -    --Y--
0123456789    0123456789    0123456789    0123456789    0123456789    0123456789
```

Someone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why 4 languages?

Comment: sry, I changed it :)

Comment: Basically you should check X-10 and X+10 as well to see which value is the closest to Y

Comment: I haven't thought it through, but something like: compute Z = X-Y; if Z < 0 add 9; if Z >9 subtract 9; check abs Z <= 2.

Comment: In Python, you could use the condition `(2 + X - Y) % 10 <= 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in javascript, but should do the job in any language with some changes. Look that I'm taking the modulus of each number to make them in range `[0, 9]`

```js
const isInRange = (x, y, range) => {
  const
    absDiff = Math.abs(x % 10 - y % 10),
    modRange = range % 10;
    
  return absDiff <= modRange || 10 - absDiff <= modRange;
}

console.log(isInRange(0, 9, 2))
console.log(isInRange(1, 9, 2))
console.log(isInRange(4, 7, 2))
console.log(isInRange(9, 7, 2))
console.log(isInRange(19, 7, 2))
console.log(isInRange(9, 7, 9))
```

Comment: For my case
absDiff <= modRange || 10 - absDiff <= modRange;
was already enough. And after staring at it, it seems so obvious ^^
Thank you very much!